# Server Error in '/PSS.NET' Application

Tags: .net, web-applications

iam trying to run an application visual studio 2008..
got this error..
help me to proceed..
thanks a lot in advance.

### Server Error in '/PSS.NET' Application.

> Configuration Error  Description: An
>   error occurred during the processing
>   of a configuration file required to
>   service this request. Please review
>   the specific error details below and
>   modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load
>   file or assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine,
>   Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 21:      
>   Line 22:           Line 23:
>                 
>   Line 24:              
>   Line 25:
>
> Source File:
>   D:\ISSM\Dynamic\Code\PSSFinalSQL\PSS.NET\web.config
>   Line: 23
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following
>   information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine,
>   Version=11.5.3300.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' could
>   not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is
>   turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry
>   value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]
>   (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some
>   performance penalty associated with
>   assembly bind failure logging. To turn
>   this feature off, remove the registry
>   value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.3074;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3074

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the message carefully you will see:

1. There is a problem with a configuration file (i.e. `web.config`).
2. The problem is that there is an assembly that cannot be found (`'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine`)

Either that assembly needs to be in the GAC or in the web application's `bin` folder.